# lxml: Unknown includemode or @method attribute

Tags: python, plone, lxml, diazo

I've setup [Diazo](http://diazo.org) on a fresh Ubuntu 12.04LTS [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) box, using the following steps:

1. `apt-get update`
2. `apt-get install python-setuptools`
3. `apt-get install build-essential python2.7-dev libxslt1-dev`
4. `easy_install -U diazo`
5. Followed the instructions in [Diazo Quickstart](http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) (adding the latest [bootstrap.py](http://downloads.buildout.org/2/bootstrap.py))

The Diazo example in the Quickstart works fine (with the minor addition of `read_network = true` to `[filter:theme]`).

However, when I add my existing project (that works on other machines), I get the following error from `bin/paster serve` when trying to view the site

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.33.1', 50171)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/test/eggs/Paste-1.7.5.1-py2.7.egg/paste/httpserver.py", line 1068, in process_request_in_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 638, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/vagrant/test/eggs/Paste-1.7.5.1-py2.7.egg/paste/httpserver.py", line 442, in handle
    BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 340, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/vagrant/test/eggs/Paste-1.7.5.1-py2.7.egg/paste/httpserver.py", line 437, in handle_one_request
    self.wsgi_execute()
  File "/home/vagrant/test/eggs/Paste-1.7.5.1-py2.7.egg/paste/httpserver.py", line 287, in wsgi_execute
    self.wsgi_start_response)
  File "/home/vagrant/test/eggs/Paste-1.7.5.1-py2.7.egg/paste/urlmap.py", line 203, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/vagrant/test/eggs/diazo-1.0b1-py2.7.egg/diazo/wsgi.py", line 353, in __call__
    transform_middleware = self.get_transform_middleware()
  File "/home/vagrant/test/eggs/diazo-1.0b1-py2.7.egg/diazo/wsgi.py", line 342, in get_transform_middleware
    tree=self.compile_theme(),
  File "/home/vagrant/test/eggs/diazo-1.0b1-py2.7.egg/diazo/wsgi.py", line 337, in compile_theme
    xsl_params=xsl_params,
  File "/home/vagrant/test/eggs/diazo-1.0b1-py2.7.egg/diazo/compiler.py", line 106, in compile_theme
    read_network=read_network,
  File "/home/vagrant/test/eggs/diazo-1.0b1-py2.7.egg/diazo/rules.py", line 164, in process_rules
    rules_doc = annotate_rules(rules_doc)
  File "/home/vagrant/test/eggs/diazo-1.0b1-py2.7.egg/diazo/utils.py", line 49, in __call__
    result = self.xslt(*args, **kw)
  File "xslt.pxi", line 556, in lxml.etree.XSLT.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:110044)
XSLTApplyError: 
            ERROR: Unknown includemode or @method attribute
```

I'ved tried setting different `includemodes` suggested in the [deployment docs](http://docs.diazo.org/en/latest/deployment.html), with no success.

The only other difference between my project and the demo that I can (currently) spot, other than my extended rules, is that I include `xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"`

What is causing the error and how can fix it?

Comment: I've also tried skipping the easy_install step and pinning lxml to 2.3 in buildout, with no success.

Comment: I've also tried isolating the buildout within a virtualenv to no avail.

Comment: [See: errors-and-message](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#errors-and-messages)

Answer (score 0):

i faced somehow same problem with lxml .
try not to include anything in your xml file. 
but write the code directly into the file.

i still dont why this happens !!

Hope it gives you a lead ..

Comment: [See: errors-and-message](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#errors-and-messages)